# How to import vssettings from VS2013 into VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I tried to import my vssettings from Visual Studio 2013 into Visual Studio 2012 but I got an error saying it was created from a unsupported application.

How can I convert the settings to be used by VS2012?

Comment: Why the negative votes?! It's a perfect valid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered by myself.
You just open the file with a text editor and change from

```
<ApplicationIdentity version="12.0"/>
```

to

```
<ApplicationIdentity version="11.0"/>
```